# pixi.js - gaps while drawing lines on Graphics

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawing, pixi.js

I'm trying to make a simple graphics program for doodling and such, but I'm having some trouble with the line tools provided by PIXI.Graphics().

I draw lines by using events such as pointerdown, pointermove, etc. Saving the last coordinate and then using moveTo and lineTo to draw a continuous line until you trigger pointerup. When drawing a line however [gaps appear in semi-regular intervals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnSd4.png).

Those gaps are always in the color used in the beginFill() fill statement. Even if I use multiple colors, they will appear in the line, making it not really "gaps" but [wrongly colored lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHTbb.png).

When a long line is drawn via code, [the same error does not seem to occur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZvul.png).
I'm quite stumped by the behaviour and it would be nice if you could help me out!

Here is the code I used:

```
let app;
let graphics;
var isDrawing = false;
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var count = 0;
window.onload = function(){
    
    var canvasContainer = document.getElementById("areaCanvasContainer");
    //Create a Pixi Application
    app = new PIXI.Application({ 
        width: 600,
        height: 500,
        antialias: false,
        transparent: false,
        resolution: 1,
        forceCanvas: false,
        backgroundColor: 0xFFFFFF
    });
    canvasContainer.appendChild(app.view);
    
    graphics = new PIXI.Graphics();
    graphics.interactive = true;
    graphics.buttonMode = true;
    
    graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
    graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 600, 500);
    graphics.endFill();
    graphics.lineStyle(3, 0x000000,1.0,0.5,false);
    
    graphics.on("pointerdown", mousedown);
    graphics.on("pointermove", mousemove);
    graphics.on("pointerup", mouseup);
    graphics.on("pointerupoutside", mouseup);
    
    app.stage.addChild(graphics);
}

function mousedown(e) {
    x = e.data.global.x;
    y = e.data.global.y;
    isDrawing = true;
}

function mousemove(e) {
    if (isDrawing === true) {
        if(Math.abs(x - e.data.global.x) > 2 || Math.abs(y - e.data.global.y ) > 2 ){
            drawLine(graphics, x, y, e.data.global.x, e.data.global.y);
            x = e.data.global.x;
            y = e.data.global.y;
        }
    }
}

function mouseup(e) {
    if (isDrawing === true) {
        drawLine(graphics, x, y, e.data.global.x, e.data.global.y);
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        isDrawing = false;
    }
}

function drawLine(graphics, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    if(!(x1 === x2 && y1 === y2)){
        
        graphics.endFill();
        graphics.moveTo(x1, y1);
        graphics.lineTo(x2, y2);
    }
}
```